# Using mysql's CONCAT() for a column name

Tags: php, mysql, database, concatenation

I want to `UPDATE` a database column by concatenating a string with a function. let's say that I have two columns `sum_likes_c1` and `sum_likes_c2` and I have a function called `$class` has 1 or 2 value

so I want the query to update the column based on `$class` value

my current code (not working):

```
if (isset($function)) {
    $class = 1;
    } else $class = 2;

    $update_likes = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE posts SET CONCAT(sum_likes_c,'$class') ='$total_likes' WHERE id='$post_id'");
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns, consider whether your schema design is optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONCAT() is a **string** function, you cannot use it for column names which are **identifiers**. You have to concatenate in PHP. [See how to do it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7537500/285587)

That said, if you need to concatenate to get a coulmn name, most likely (like 99%) your database design is wrong. There must be a separate table to collect your likes, preferably using INSERT, not UPDATE

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
if (isset($function)) {
$class = 1;
} else $class = 2;

$column = "sum_likes_c" . $class;

$update_likes = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE posts SET ".$column." = ".$total_likes." WHERE id = ".$post_id);
```

Comment: Please be wary of SQL injection. Use prepared statements and white-listing.